# Visual Studio 2022: Git Diff for all changed files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Is it possible in Visual Studio 2022 to browse through all changed files? In the *Git Changes* window, a double click on single file opens the diff, but I would like to rewiew all the changed files before committing.

(In JetBrains Rider, it's possible to browse through all changed files in the Diff window)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe single-click diff is currently possible before committing (it is after). But we can up-vote [this suggestion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Single-click-to-show-file-diff-in-Git-Ch/10220430?port=1025&fsid=b954e492-7c7a-46e6-8518-049d2b96c91e) for it.